# Create random integer in range from random double

Tags: c++, random, mersenne-twister

I get random double number [0,1) from mersenne twister. 
How would I get random [0,x) from mersenne twister output?

Mersenne twister outputs either random integer in total range or random [0,1)

It is important that it is evenly distributed, so I doubt that basic 
floor(mersenneRandom()*x) will do.

if it does, then great.

Comment: Why does the implementation of mersenne twister you're using provide a double? The basic algorithm provides random bits which are most easily assembled into integral values, producing random values uniformly distributed over the integral type's range. If you're getting doubles then something in the API is taking those integral values and doing the transformation to double.

Comment: Plus one for asking. There is too much code out there which abuses random number generators,

Comment: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another case for your [favorite reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)!

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1, 2);
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)) generates values in [1,2), and the site explains how to do it for arbitrary [a,b)!

If you need integers, use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

`floor(mersenneRandom()*x)` does indeed not work because the difference between a `double`-value and the next greater one becomes greater than one for big numbers. You would skip all integers between those two values.

Comment: so mathFloor wil leven for small numbers on 100 000 000 requests return unevenly distrubuted numbers, although RNG worked correctly

Comment: @Tree I *believe* that this should be fine for small numbers, but problems with RNG are often **very** subtle, I might be missing something. You **really** should not try to handcraft stuff like this and use implementations by people who spent more time researching RNG, such as those mentioned above or `boost::random` if you cannot use C++11. As you might have noticed earlier, even Bathseba, a good and experienced programmer screwed up on the first try (just to show you how hard it is to get this right).

Comment: I used example form st::uniform_int_distribution but I still wonder if it is the best solution, because it incorporates double into calculation of uniform distribution. I am still looking for finite solution where you get random(x) which returns [0,x) but didn't find it. For now, this solution gives best results on even spread

Comment: @Tree `std::uniform_int_distribution` has nothing to do with `double`s, it just maps the random bits `std::mt19337` (the mersenne twister)  yields as uniformly as possible to the integer-range you provide.